# Zonas verdes vs. zonas verde

Tags: número-gramatical

¿Por qué no es "Está rodeado de amplias [zonas](https://www.hidalgosdeespana.es/centros/colegio-mayor-marques-de-la-ensenada/) verdes (plural) y de ocio" en el siguiente párrafo? Muchas gracias !

> "Se trata de un edificio de bella estampa y arquitectura, y, en su entorno, se halla el mayor complejo universitario de Madrid (Universidad Politécnica, Complutense de Madrid, San Pablo CEU). Está rodeado de amplias zonas verde y de ocio, como el Parque del Oeste, el Centro Comercial Príncipe Pío, etc."

Comment: A mí me parece que se trata de una errata. El adjetivo debe concordar en género y número con el nombre al que acompaña, como indicas.

Comment: No dirías "...rodeada de importantes zonas industrial", sino "industriales", pero sí dirías "zonas de catástrofe" o "de ocio". Me parece también que debería ser "zonas verdes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser un error o bien que se esté refiriendo a las zonas de aparcamiento llamadas zonas **verde**, **azul**,... por el color que las distingue.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Answer (score 0):

Opino que es porque "zona verde" es un concepto. Verde ya deja de ser el adjetivo que describe el color de la zona.